# when I clicked event, I want to change text color

Tags: fullcalendar

I thought it work...but nothing happen. 
what else I can do?

```
eventClick: function(event, element) {
    alert(event.title);
    event.title = "CLICKED!";
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
}
```

Comment: when you code javascript, make sure the alligator winks... `{ };`  you're example has some simple typographical errors

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens is because you call `'rerenderEvents'` after changing the color of the element, so it instantly gets rerendered again. In order to keep the changed color you have to set the element's [`className`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) property, or just don't call `'rerenderEvents'`